# Block-treatment interaction for Randomized Block Design (RCBD) and Generalized Random Block Design (GRBD)

Tags: anova, interaction, experiment-design, blocking, two-way

I understand that RCBD experiments usually only contain one observation per cell (block-treatment combination). Also, there should be no interaction between the treatments and blocks.

In GRBD, there is more than one observation per cell (block-treatment combination), and this allows for interaction between the blocks and treatments in the model.

My question is, why is this the case? Why does the presence of >1 observation per cell mean that there is now possibly interaction?

Comment: just count degrees of freedom ...